# Error saving Entity dynamics crm 2011

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dynamics-crm-2011, xrm

I have an error that I can not repair.

Im developing an application that takes a guid as a parameter and "clone" that entity in another. (I know I can do this through javascript, the problem is the CRM server don't have the required rollup and I can't update it).

The projects works fine when I'm debugging in my computer, but when I deploy it to production server it just crash. My first guess was that it was an authentication problem, but I modified the authentication rules in IIS and impersonate any windows user that use the app with mine but didn't worked anyway.

The error it throws is: -2146233088 System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal An error occured while processing this request. at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceContext.SaveChanges(SaveChangesOptions options) at Ambiente.DataAccess.Entities.CRMOrdenDeCompra.CreateOrdenDeCompra(Guid guidSolicitudDeCompra) in c:\Wip\Projects\Dev\CRMINTEGRATION\CRMINTEGRATION.DataAccess\Entities\CRMOrdenDeCompra.cs:line 42 at CRMINTEGRATION.WebApp.Controllers.RequestController.CreateOrdenDeCompra(String guid) in c:\Wip\Projects\Dev\CRMINTEGRATION\CRMINTEGRATION.WebApp\Controllers\RequestController.cs:line 22

The code that insert the entity:

```
        var solicituddecompraContext = new CRMSolicitudDeCompra();
        var solicituddecompra = new new_solicituddecompra();
        solicituddecompra = context.new_solicituddecompraSet.FirstOrDefault(q => q.new_solicituddecompraId == parameterGuid);

        new_ordendecompra ordendecompra = new new_ordendecompra();
        ordendecompra.new_ordendecompraId = Guid.NewGuid();
        ordendecompra.new_name = string.Format(solicituddecompra.new_name + " ({0})", DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss"));
        ordendecompra.new_FechaRequirida = solicituddecompra.new_Fecharequerida;
        ordendecompra.new_Tipodesolicitud = solicituddecompra.new_Tipodesolicitud;
        ordendecompra.new_Observaciones = solicituddecompra.new_observaciones;
        ordendecompra.new_Numerodesolicitud = solicituddecompra.new_SolicitudNo;

        var detallerequisicion = CRMDetalleRequisicion.getDetalleRequisicion(context, guidSolicitudDeCompra);

        context.AddObject(ordendecompra);
        context.SaveChanges();
```

I generated the XRM class of CRM with the crmsvcutil.exe. So the name of the classes you see in the code are actually the name of the entities in CRM. All of the above works fine until it reaches the method entidad.SaveChanges().

Ps. As you can see in the code, english is not my native language. Feel free to correct me if I make any mistake. I will apreciate that :).

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Can you really use EF to add data to a CRM 2011 instance ? I thought you'd have to use the Execute method from the OrganizationServiceProxy to do that...

Comment: @Francis You can generate classes and a context using CrmSvcUtil - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327844.aspx

Comment: @Francis as glosrob mentioned you can generate a context class using this utility. This make your life easier because you can work with the entities using EF.